# A Question About Scope - jQuery

Tags: jquery, scope, global-variables

I have this function which features this bit of code (edited for succinctness):

```
(function ($) {

    // mouseenter event for each menu item
    $menuItems.bind('mouseenter', function (e) {});

})(jQuery);
```

What I would like to do is access $menuItems from this function in other functions.

For example:

```
$("#products a").click(function(){
    $menuItems.unbind("mouseenter");
});
```

I believe this is a matter of scope?

I'm unsure how to do this?

Comment: Define it with `window.$menuItems` and it will be global

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A third option:

```
(function ($) {

    var $menuItems = /* whatever */;

    $menuItems.bind('mouseenter', function (e) {});

    // "export" the variable
    window.$menuItems = $menuItems;
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Thanks to everyone that helped! This answered worked the best in my code setup. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

before your code, add

```
var $menuItems
```

and it should work. Btw you've got parse error in your code, you're missing

```
});
```

(so it would look like)

```
(function ($) {

    // mouseenter event for each menu item
    $menuItems.bind('mouseenter', function (e) {
         //something
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: menuItems is already declared in a var. I'm not sure if that is what is stopping me from getting this to work? Here's an abbreviated fiddle of what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/k9eAn/

Answer (score 0):

You would have to declare $menuItems in the global namespace, literally like so as an example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var $menuItems = something;
</script>
```

Your IDE might complain that $menuItems isn't defined, but to javascript it would be.

As far as scope is concerned, if you have a function or anonymous method, and have a line like this *inside* it:

`var myVar = somethingElse;`

then scope defines that myVar is only known to anything else inside that function or method.

If you put your declaration outside of the body of a function then it will be available to any function/method that is available.
As for best practices, this may not always be a good thing, it's similar to using globals and listening to your comp.sci professor, but if you know the scope of your code and are sensible about your naming convention so that your name won't conflict with anything else, you're generally ok.